# Drawable Start icon backgroubd color

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android app and want to have a login screen such as
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TKdE.png)

my current screen looks
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4xCp.png)

How do I set the background color of the `drawableStart` of an `EditText`?

activity_login.xml

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_element_height"
            android:background="@drawable/et_backgrount"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_white_24dp"
            android:textColor="@color/edittext_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edittext_hint"/>
```

et_backgrount.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#f36774" />            
        <size
            android:height="100dp"
            android:width="100dp" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#f36774" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should definitely work on improving the readability of your question. I understand english is probably not your primary language but some instances are clear cases of not even rereading the post, even getting to the point where one xml line is missing.

Comment: Use spelling correction tools please and visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link to know more about asking a question properly.

Comment: if you want something like this, don't use drawable left, use different widgets along with edit text and set background.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about adding a background to the drawableStart . But an alternative solution would be to use an image view along with the edit text. And put them next to each other horizontally, may be using linearlayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="@dimen/form_element_height"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/form_element_height"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_white_24dp"
     android:background="@drawable/SOME_WHITE_BACKGROUND>
  </ImageView>
  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/form_element_height"
     android:background="@drawable/et_backgrount"

     android:textColor="@color/edittext_color"
     android:textColorHint="@color/edittext_hint">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```